# Moodle:How to Customize frontPage

Tags: php, moodle

I have to remove few hyperlinks from header in index.php file of moodle. I am unable to find the exact file in moodle folder that in which file I have to remove href tag.

can you please help me in how to remove hyperlinks from header of the index.php of moodle. ??

Comment: This is not a suitable question for Stack Overflow. However, any decent IDE will have a `search whole project` option. Use that and type in something that will identify the link you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

It's rather hard to guess what exactly do you want to remove however you can customize most parts of Moodle by [overriding the renderer](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Overriding_a_renderer) in your theme.